# Why is factory bot nulling out passed in attributes? How can I get it to not do that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a simple factory

```
  factory :imported_object do
    sequence(:source_id) { |n| "id_#{n}" }
    source { 'default_source' }
  end
```

and I'm trying to test that it allows duplicate source_ids, but only from different sources. However, I'm not able to assign these attributes at the same time. I can assign either individually, but

`imported_object = build(:imported_object, source: '5', source_id: 'different_source')`

causes both objects to have the value `nil` in the resulting `imported_object`

How can I get FactoryBot to work here?

Comment: Is there a model behind this factory?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it's just a limitation of factory bot though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that your columns are called `source` and `source_id`. factory_bot makes an assumption that `source` is an association and `source_id` is the foreign key for that association.

This issue comes up a lot, and we are tracking it at https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/1142.